# Sort a VARCHAR column in SQL Server that contains numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in which data has letters with numbers.

For example:

```
1 name
2 names .... 
100 names
```

When sorting this data, it is not sorted correctly, how can I fix this? I made a request but it doesn’t sort correctly.

```
select name_subagent
from Subagent
order by 
    case IsNumeric(name_subagent) 
        when 1 then Replicate('0', 100 - Len(name_subagent)) + name_subagent
        else name_subagent
end
```

[image]

Comment: You can't easily handle this in SQL Server, without resorting to something like a UDF which can remove all letters from a string.  Your best bet is to just store the number and text components in separate columns.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
select name_subagent
from Subagent
order by CAST(LEFT(name_subagent, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name_subagent + 'a') - 1) as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression will find the first occurrence of a letter withing a string and assume anything prior to this position is a number.
You will need to adapt this statement to your needs as apparently your data is not in Latin characters.
With a bit of tweaking you should be able to achieve exactly what you're looking for:

```
select 
    name_subagent
from 
    Subagent
order by 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(name_subagent,0,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',name_subagent)) as numeric)
```

Note, the `'%[A-Z]%'` expression. This will only look for the first occurrence of a **letter** within the string.
I'm not considering special characters such as '**!**', '**#**' and so on. This is the bit you might want to play around with and adapt to your needs.

Comment: I made your request but gives an error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
I have no date data in the column, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you're going to have to play around and find the ideal regular expression for your case. You're getting this error because the regular expression you're using is picking up more characters other than numbers. If you're trying to run my statement AS IS over a string in a non-latin alphabet, then it will definitely not work. I'm not familiar with this language so you need to search the correct regular expression for non-numeric characters.

Comment: in the column I have Russian, English and numbers.
for example: 10пример, 101example